# Redirect file extension (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was wondering if it were possible to redirect certain ending file types to another extension. It's been done before on a site I visited, but I am unable to find out how.

For exmaple:

If my website had php files and the extension was www.example.com/testfile.php and I want it to show up on the URL as www.example.com/testfile.aspx, how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1.php [L]
```

or if you would prefer to actually save the files as aspx on the server instead of redirecting to a PHP script, do something like:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.aspx$ $1.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: That would only match URLs in the document root, not in sub-directories.